# how to send/receive multiple data? python socket?

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to send/receive multiple data. Server perfectly send file's name and file's data. problem is in client. I have created a two variable named filename and filedata. filename variable received filename with file's data. filedata received nothing because filename received all filename and filedata. I don't know why filename received filename+data? how do i fix that problem?

here is my code:

## server.py

```
import socket

def send():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 9999
    address = (host, port)

    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(address)
    sock.listen(5)
    print('listining for connection...')

    con,addr = sock.accept()
    print('Got connection from',addr)

    file1name = 'file1.txt'
    con.send(file1name.encode('utf-8'))
    file1data = 'this is file 1'
    con.send(file1data.encode('utf-8'))

    file2name = 'file2.txt'
    con.send(file2name.encode('utf-8'))
    file2data = 'this is file 2'
    con.send(file2data.encode('utf-8'))

    con.close()
    sock.shutdown(1)
    sock.close()
    print('connection closed!')

send()
```

## client.py

```
import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 9999
address = (host, port)

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(address)
print('connected to', address)

while True:
    filename = sock.recv(60).decode('utf-8')
    if not filename:
        break
    print('filename -', filename)
    data = sock.recv(60).decode('utf-8')
    print('data -', data)


sock.shutdown(1)
sock.close()
```

## output server.py

```
listining for connection...
Got connection from ('127.0.0.1', 36886)
connection closed!
```

## output client.py

```
connected to ('localhost', 9999)
filename - file1.txtthis is file 1file2.txtthis is file 2
data -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you have to send the data size to the client before it start to receive.

I assume the server send an unsigned int 32bit(4byte) to represent the size.

See soc.recv(4) in client.py

## server.py

```py
from socket import *
import os
import ctypes

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9999
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
BUF_SIZE = 1024
PATH = './uploads'

soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
soc.bind(ADDRESS)
soc.listen(5)
print('listen for connection...')
con,addr = soc.accept()
print('got connection from', addr)
print('-------------------------')

def sendFile(socket, path):
    filename = os.path.basename(path)

    filename_bytes = filename.encode('utf-8')
    filename_size = ctypes.c_uint32(len(filename_bytes))
    file_size = ctypes.c_uint32(os.stat(path).st_size)

    socket.send(bytes(filename_size)) # send uint32 (4 bytes)
    socket.send(filename_bytes)
    socket.send(bytes(file_size)) # send uint32 (4 bytes)

    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        filecontent = f.read(BUF_SIZE)
        while filecontent:
            socket.send(filecontent)
            filecontent = f.read(BUF_SIZE)

files = os.listdir(PATH)
num_files = ctypes.c_uint32(len(files))
con.send(bytes(num_files))
for file in files:
    sendFile(con, os.path.join(PATH, file))
```

## client.py

```py
from socket import *
import os
import ctypes

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9999
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
BUF_SIZE = 1024
PATH = './downloads'

soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
soc.connect(ADDRESS)
print('connected to', ADDRESS)

def recvFile(socket):
    tmp = soc.recv(4)
    filename_size = int.from_bytes(tmp, byteorder='little')
    print('filename_size =', filename_size)
    filename = soc.recv(filename_size).decode('utf-8')
    print('filename =', filename)
    tmp = soc.recv(4)
    file_size = int.from_bytes(tmp, byteorder='little')
    print('file_size =', file_size)

    with open(os.path.join(PATH, filename), 'wb') as f:
        while file_size > 0:
            filecontent = soc.recv(min(BUF_SIZE, file_size))
            f.write(filecontent)
            file_size -= len(filecontent)
    print('data recvd')

tmp = soc.recv(4)
num_files = int.from_bytes(tmp, byteorder='little')

for i in range(num_files):
    print('{}/{}'.format(i+1, num_files))
    recvFile(soc)

soc.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
soc.close()
print('socket closed')
```

Comment: I appreciated your answer. but i don't understand why you used unsigned variable? please explain this to me.

Comment: The purpose is to send the size to inform the client how many bytes are coming. So I choose unsigned integer since size is always >= 0. You can also choose uint16 or other type of uint depending on the range.